# How to store object in a cookie so I can use it for further sessions?

Tags: javascript, object, cookies

Hi,

I have html like this:

```
<div id="inputarea" style="color:black;font-size:15px;">
```

I want to store the style data into a cookie so I did this:

```
setCookie('savedstyle',inputarea.style);
```

So in my next session inputarea should load the data from that cookie and set it as the style for the inputarea like this:

```
if(getCookie('savedstyle')) {
  inputarea.style = getCookie('savedstyle');
 }
```

nothing happens because the value stored in the cookie looks something like this: [object CSS properties]. Why is that? How can I store the value properly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.style` in JS just stores setters for CSS attributes. It's not useful for reading information.

If you just want to store the inline style use:

```js
setCookie('savedstyle', inputarea.getAttribute('style'))
```

and to retrieve

```js
inputarea.setAttribute('style', getCookie('savedstyle'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try these. These are some boilerplate functions I use for my projects when I need it.

```js
readCookie = (cname) =>
{
    let name = cname + '=';
    let decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(window.document.cookie);
    let ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(let i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) 
    {
        let c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') 
        {
        c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0)
        {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return '';
}
createCookie=(cname, cvalue)=>
{
    let d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (10*24*60*60*1000));
    let expires = 'expires='+ d.toUTCString();
    window.document.cookie = cname + '=' + cvalue + ';' + expires + ';path=/';
}
deleteCookie = (name) =>
{
  if(readCookie(name)) 
  {
    window.document.cookie = name + '=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT';
  }
}
```

The readCookie function reads a cookie by the name.
createCookie you give it a name and a value, and the deleteCookie deletes a cookie by name. Pretty self explanatory :D.